# Загрузка страничек iframe yii2

Tags: yii2, iframe

Подскажите пожалуйста, как открыть в Yii2 произвольную страничку без стилей и т.д. 
Пробую такой код

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = 'About';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-about">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<iframe src="contact.php" name="mainframe" width="100%"> </iframe>

</div>
```

src  пробовал все и "google.com" или "abc.com" или "site/contact" и другие варианты, и вообще как в Yii2 с минимальной кровью вывести,отобразить в фрейме стороннюю страничку не имеющую никакого отношения к модели сайта. Какой путь указывать, как указывать - чтобы во фрейме отражалась указанная страничка.

т.е. любой сторонний или локальный файл, чтобы указать ссылку и фрейм показал содержимое. Пока в iframe только Object not found...

XAMPP, apache, htdocs - корень для advanced конфигурации yii2.

все вводимые мной пути в код файла, без проблем отражаются в браузере, все указанные странички и www существуют, очевидно Yii2 производит какую-то  либо подстановку либо корректировку пути и iframe отражает что объект не найден...

Comment: Конкретно какой url? Просто некоторые сайт, например google не отображаются в iframe

Comment: Речь идет о любом стороннем файле или url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать так:

```
<iframe src="http://name-site.com" name="mainframe" width="100%"> </iframe>
```

Для доступа к текущему хосту обращаться так:

```
<iframe src="/some-path" name="mainframe" width="100%"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Более гибко будет использовать такой синтаксис.

```
<iframe src="http<?= !YII_DEBUG ? 's' : '' ?>://<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/controller/action/get-params">
</iframe>
```